# Cyclotomic field (again)

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields, galois-extensions

Let be $\zeta=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{55}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{55}\right)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. Obviously $G:=\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\cong\left(\mathbb Z_2,+\right)\times\left(\mathbb Z_4,+\right)\times\left(\mathbb Z_5,+\right)=H.$ Since there are 3 subgroups of order 2 of $H$, there are 3 subfield $L_1,L_2,L_3$ of $K$ with $[K:L_i]=2,$ but (again) how can I express these subfields "explicitely" as fixed field of a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(K)$? And how can I find such subgroups? I think I'm missing something from the Fundamental theorem of Galois theory...

There are some more tasks related to this, but maybe later.

Anyway, thx for help.

Comment: My argument [from the answer to your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361906/11619) spells this out. The three fields are $L_1=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5,\cos(2\pi/11))$, $L_2=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{11},\cos(2\pi/5))$ and $L_3=\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/55))$. The respective order two automorphisms complex conjugate $\zeta_{11}$, $\zeta_5$ or both while leave the other unchanged in the first two cases.

Comment: Alternatively the respective automorphisms map $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^{21}$, $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^{34}$ and $\zeta\mapsto \zeta^{-1}$ You get the exponents by CRT-combining $\pm1$ modulo $5$ and $11$ to a residue class modulo $55$ in various ways. Note that $21^2\equiv 34^2\equiv(-1)^2\pmod{55}$.

Comment: This same basic recipe gives you the three fields when $\zeta$ is of order $n=pq$ with the odd primes $p,q$ satisfying the property $\gcd(p-1,q-1)=2$. IOW at least one of them is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks, we can see, that the only real subfield is the $L_3$. However, is there any another way to realize this fact?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen And again, which of the extensions $K/L_i$ are cyclic? I just do not see a way of finding cycle subgroups of $H$...

Comment: If you view the Galois group as $G=\Bbb{Z}_{10}\times\Bbb{Z}_4$, then the overall complex conjugation (with fixed field $L_3$) is the element $(5,2)$, and the other order two automorphisms are $(5,0)$ (with fixed field $L_1$) and $(0,2)$ (with fixed field $L_2$). Do you know how to check whether, say, $G/\langle (5,2)\rangle$ is cyclic or not?

Comment: I guess I could use First homomorphism theorem. Since $|G|=40$ and $|\langle(5,2)\rangle|=2$, so order of $G/\langle(5,2)\rangle$ is 20, thus it can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Right?

Comment: Correct! In one of those groups all the elements have order dividing ten. Which of those order two subgroups $H_i,i=1,2,3,$ have the property that $10x\in H_i$ for all $x\in G$?

Comment: Am I missing something? I suppose all of them has the property.

Comment: $10(1,1)=(10,10)=(0,2)$ does not belong to the subgroups $H_3=\langle(5,2)\rangle$ or $H_1=\langle(5,0)\rangle$, so it looks like the order of $(1,1)+H_3$ and $(1,1)+H_1$ is twenty, no?

Comment: Oh, of course. So $H_1$ and $H_3$ are cyclic and for the last we have $10(x,y)=(0,2y)=(0,0)\text{ or }(0,2)$ so $H_2=\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the usual convention$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\ze}{\zeta}$ that
$\si_a$ denotes the automorphism with $\si_a(\ze)=\ze^a$. The solutions of
$a^2\equiv1\pmod{55}$ are $a\equiv\pm1$, $\pm21$. The elements of order $2$
are $\si_{-1}$, $\si_{21}$ and $\si_{-21}$. The $L_i$ are the fixed fields
of these, viz., $\Bbb Q(\ze+\ze^{-1})$, $\Bbb Q(\ze+\ze^{21})$
and $\Bbb Q(\ze+\ze^{-21})$.